# Join optional column with JPA and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am working with hibernate through JPA (backend for testing is h2, but the same issue happens on other engines) and have encountered a problem when joining optional columns and filtering on them.

I have the following data model:

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @Nullable
    private Assignee assignee;
}

@Entity
public class Assignee {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;
}
```

And three entities:

- `Assignee{id = 1, name = kitty}`
- `Ticket{id = 1, assignee = null}`
- `Ticket{id = 2, assignee = 1}`

Now, I am querying tickets with jpql:

- `select t from Ticket t` yields both tickets, as expected.
- `select t from Ticket t where t.assignee is null` yields ticket 1 only, as expected.
- `select t from Ticket t where t.assignee.name = :name` with `name=kitty` yields ticket 2 only, as expected.

However, linking the two filters together in an OR clause does not behave as expected: `select t from Ticket t where (t.assignee is null or t.assignee.name = :name)` with `name=kitty` only yields ticket 2, while the query should match ticket 1 as well (because assignee may be null). When checking the hibernate debug log, the following SQL query is generated:

```
SELECT
  ticket0_.id          AS id1_1_,
  ticket0_.assignee_id AS assignee2_1_
FROM Ticket ticket0_ CROSS JOIN Assignee assignee1_
WHERE ticket0_.assignee_id = assignee1_.id AND (ticket0_.assignee_id IS NULL OR assignee1_.name = ?)
```

The condition `ticket0_.assignee_id = assignee1_.id` is obviously never satisfied for ticket 1 since it has no assignee, so hibernate translated this query incorrectly.

Is there any way for me to fix this?

Comment: This ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654023/how-do-i-query-hibernate-for-object-where-property-may-be-null-or-specific-value

Comment: @slckin no, that's a different api.

Answer (score 0):

On your `SELECT` statement, you indicated this expression `t.assignee.name`. Though you have not explicitly used a `JOIN` operation in your `SELECT` statement, traversing from the `Ticket` entity to the `Assignee` entity to get the `name` property will require a NATURAL JOIN between the 2 entities. Thus, you will see a `ticket0_.assignee_id = assignee1_.id` in your output SQL.

You can rewrite you query:

```
SELECT t from Ticket t WHERE (t.assignee IS NULL) OR (t.assignee IS NOT NULL AND t.assignee.name = :name)
```

Or try using an OUTER JOIN instead:

```
SELECT t FROM Ticket t LEFT JOIN Assignee a WHERE a.name = :name
```